# Converting a flat multidimensional array into a hierarchical array -- for albums and photo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data

So I am trying to list photo albums where each album contains individual photos. This is similar to categories where each category cotains posts.
I have two database tables, namely "albums" and "photos". 
The albums table has columns id, album_name, and album_description.
The photos table has columns id, photo_is_in, photo_name and photo_description.

I used INNER JOIN to combine  the albums and photos table to produce the flat $albums array below:

```
<?php

$albums  = [
['album_id' => '1', 'photo_id' => '41', 'album_name' => 'album_1', 'album_description' => 'Album 1 description', 'photo_is_in' => 'album_1', 'photo_name' => 'photo_1.jpg', 'photo_description' => 'Photo 1 description'],

['album_id' => '1', 'photo_id' => '42', 'album_name' => 'album_1', 'album_description' => 'Album 1 description', 'photo_is_in' => 'album_1', 'photo_name' => 'photo_2.jpg', 'photo_description' => 'Photo 2 description'],

//==================

['album_id' => '2', 'photo_id' => '43', 'album_name' => 'album_2', 'album_description' => 'Album 2 description', 'photo_is_in' => 'album_2', 'photo_name' => 'photo_3.jpg', 'photo_description' => 'Photo 3 description'],

['album_id' => '2', 'photo_id' => '44', 'album_name' => 'album_2', 'album_description' => 'Album 2 description', 'photo_is_in' => 'album_2', 'photo_name' => 'photo_4.jpg', 'photo_description' => 'Photo 4 description'],

];

?>
```

I want to turn the $albums array above into a hierarchical array like below:

```
<?php

$sameAlbums = Array(

        'album_1' => Array( //comes from 'album_name' => 'album_1' in the $data array above
            'album_id' => '1',
            'album_description' => 'Album 1 description',
            'album_1' => Array( //comes from 'photo_is_in' => 'album_1' in the $data array above

                'photo_1.jpg' => Array( 
                    'photo_id' => '41',
                    'photo_description' => 'Photo 1 description',

                ), 


                'photo_2.jpg' => Array( 
                    'photo_id' => '42',
                    'photo_description' => 'Photo 2 description',

                ) 


            )

        ),

        //============================================

    'album_2' => Array( //comes from 'album_name' => 'album_2' in the $data array above
        'album_id' => '2',
        'album_description' => 'Album 2 description',
        'album_2' => Array( //comes from 'phot_is_in' => 'album_2' in the $data array above

            'photo_3.jpg' => Array( 
                'photo_id' => '43',
                'photo_description' => 'Photo 3 deescription',

            ), 


            'photo_3.jpg' => Array( 
                'photo_id' => '44',
                'photo_description' => 'Photo 4 deescription',

            ) 


        ) 

    ) 

);

?>
```

I have tried something like this which did not work as expected and I need help here:

```
<?php
$grouping = [];
foreach($albums as $albumName){
    //Grouping data by album name
    $grouping[$albumName['album_name']][] = $albumName; 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($grouping);

?>
```

I can feel my solution is not enough but then I am short of ideas.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Change `$grouping[$albumName['phot_is_in']] = $albumName[];` to `$grouping[$albumName['phot_is_in']][] = $albumName;`

Comment: Have a look at this question: [how-to-group-array-data-returned-by-left-join-query-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612653/how-to-group-array-data-returned-by-left-join-query-in-php)

Comment: Hey @Paul Spiegel, I need each of the main album array to contain album_id and album description as well as photos where each photo is as an array containing photo_id, photo_description and photo_name etc. But my solution only puts everything in the album array without each photo having its own away

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the syntax error you pointed out. But it did not make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```php
$grouping = [];
foreach($albums as $album) {
    if (!isset($grouping[$album['album_id']])) {
        $grouping[$album['album_id']] = [
            'album_id'          => $album['album_id'],
            'album_name'        => $album['album_name'],
            'album_description' => $album['album_description'],
            'photos' => []
        ];
    }
    $grouping[$album['album_id']]['photos'][$album['photo_id']] = [
        'photo_id'          => $album['photo_id'],
        'photo_name'        => $album['photo_name'],
        'photo_description' => $album['photo_description']
    ]; 
}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GBW65553

But usually I would just run two queries. First fetch the albums and init empty arrays for photos. Then fetch the photos and assign them to the related albums.

As @mickmackusa pointed in the comments, the indexes differ from those in the expected result in the question. This was not a mistake. This is how I would do it. But if you really need the result exactly as in your question, you can adjust the code to:

```
$grouping = [];
foreach($albums as $album) {
    if (!isset($grouping[$album['album_name']])) {
        $grouping[$album['album_name']] = [
            'album_id'          => $album['album_id'],
            'album_name'        => $album['album_name'],
            'album_description' => $album['album_description'],
            $album['album_name'] => []
        ];
    }
    $grouping[$album['album_name']][$album['album_name']][$album['photo_name']] = [
        'photo_id'          => $album['photo_id'],
        'photo_name'        => $album['photo_name'],
        'photo_description' => $album['photo_description']
    ]; 
}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/LUZIG46060

Comment: pay careful attention to where the new keys "come from" based on the inline comments in the OP's question.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel, I just tried your code but photo_1.jpg is missing from album_1 and photo_3.jpg is missing from album_2.

Comment: @PrinceBrucex Just fixed the index for photo.. See demo.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think using `album_id` and `photo_id` as indexes is more reasonable than using the names. However.. OP should understand the answer and be able to adjust the code if needed.

Comment: The OP has offered fictitious data.  If you do not provide a method that performs as requested, you may be wasting your own time.  I'm only trying to help.  Do as you like.

Comment: Paul Spiegel, thanks for the work. I am glad you helped. However, as @mic

Comment: @mickmackusa I understand your point and added a solution with the required format. But will also keep the original code, because I believe that questions and answers on SO should be as generic as possible.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel, the new solution opens and closes `album_1` array immediately without containing any photos. i.e `'album_1' => array(); 'photos' =>(); instead of 'album_1' => array( //photos here...);`

Comment: @PrinceBrucex I don't know how that happened ;-). It was correct in the demo.

Comment: I changed `$grouping[$album['album_name']]['photos'][$album['photo_name']] = [`

to 
 `$grouping[$album['album_name']][$album['album_name']][$album['photo_name']] = [`

Now everything is fine. Thanks again. You might have to edit the solution