# How to insert one table data inside another table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table server_menuresponse with columns id    menu_order  menu_name   menu_link   data_icon   sub_menu 
and another table sub_menu  with columns id mainmenu_id submenu_order   submenu_name    submenu_link    submenu_icon

I want to get all the columns of sub_menu table inside sub_menu column of server_menuresponse

[image: Result should be like this image]

I want php result should be like:

```
<?php
stdClass::__set_state(array(

   'server_menuresponse' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '1',
       'menu_order' => '1',
       'menu_name' => 'Home',
       'menu_link' => '',
       'data_icon' => '',
       'sub_menu' => 
      array (
      ),
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '2',
       'menu_order' => '2',
       'menu_name' => 'New',
       'menu_link' => '',
       'data_icon' => '',
       'sub_menu' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '5',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '3',
           'submenu_name' => 'Auto',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/auto.png',
        )),
        1 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '4',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '2',
           'submenu_name' => 'Bike',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/bike.png',
        )),
        2 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '6',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '4',
           'submenu_name' => 'Bus',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/bus.png',
        )),
        3 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '3',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '1',
           'submenu_name' => 'Car',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/car.png',
        )),
        4 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '1',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '6',
           'submenu_name' => 'Find All New Vehicle',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/new_vehicle.png',
        )),
        5 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '7',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '5',
           'submenu_name' => 'Lorry',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/lorry.png',
        )),
        6 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '2',
           'mainmenu_id' => '2',
           'submenu_order' => '7',
           'submenu_name' => 'New Vehicle Offer',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/new_offer.png',
        )),
      ),
    )),
    2 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '3',
       'menu_order' => '3',
       'menu_name' => 'Used',
       'menu_link' => '',
       'data_icon' => '',
       'sub_menu' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '11',
           'mainmenu_id' => '3',
           'submenu_order' => '3',
           'submenu_name' => 'Auto',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/auto.png',
        )),
        1 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '10',
           'mainmenu_id' => '3',
           'submenu_order' => '2',
           'submenu_name' => 'Bike',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/bike.png',
        )),
        2 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '12',
           'mainmenu_id' => '3',
           'submenu_order' => '4',
           'submenu_name' => 'Bus',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/bus.png',
        )),
        3 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '9',
           'mainmenu_id' => '3',
           'submenu_order' => '1',
           'submenu_name' => 'Car',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/car.png',
        )),
        4 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '8',
           'mainmenu_id' => '3',
           'submenu_order' => '5',
           'submenu_name' => 'Find All Used Vehicle',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => 'menu_icon/new_vehicle.png',
        )),
      ),
    )),
    3 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '4',
       'menu_order' => '4',
       'menu_name' => 'News & Reviews',
       'menu_link' => '',
       'data_icon' => '',
       'sub_menu' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '15',
           'mainmenu_id' => '4',
           'submenu_order' => '3',
           'submenu_name' => 'Car Videos',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => '',
        )),
        1 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '17',
           'mainmenu_id' => '4',
           'submenu_order' => '5',
           'submenu_name' => 'Feature Stories',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => '',
        )),
        2 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '14',
           'mainmenu_id' => '4',
           'submenu_order' => '2',
           'submenu_name' => 'Road Test',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => '',
        )),
        3 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '13',
           'mainmenu_id' => '4',
           'submenu_order' => '1',
           'submenu_name' => 'User Reviews',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => '',
        )),
        4 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'id' => '16',
           'mainmenu_id' => '4',
           'submenu_order' => '4',
           'submenu_name' => 'Write Review',
           'submenu_link' => '',
           'submenu_icon' => '',
        )),
      ),
    )),
  ),
 ),
));
?>
```

Comment: use left join to fetch records

Comment: use the left join and form the array for resulted sub_menu fields. not sure whether a table's complete row can be taken into a single field.

Comment: SQL join, then use PHP to go through the results and build the data array as it’s shown in your image.

Comment: @WillHines Yes I have join tables but how to write php code so that second table data will be in array of first table

Comment: @manafigroup: please refer the php documentation for looping through the sql resultset object and creating an array from it.

Comment: I have removed the java and jdbc tags, I don't see how those are relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have totally changed my answer!

Based on the answer to this question: [How to group array data returned by left join query in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47612653/1967095)?

I think you do two queries. Like this:

```
$data = array();

// get all the menu items 
$rows = $db->query("SELECT * from server_menuresponse order by id");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    $row['sub_menu'] = []; // blank array for sub menu
    $data[$row['id']] = $row;
}

// get sub menu items, add them to the correct menu item
$rows = $db->query("SELECT * from sub_menu order by mainmenu_id, id");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    $data[$row['mainmenu_id']]['sub_menu'][] = $row;
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: thanks for the code but the previous one was working exactly what i need this one has less code but not the one like previous one anyhow thanks once again

Comment: Sorry! I should have added a new answer instead of editing my old one. :)